# node.js async.series functions not finishing in series

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to have some functions execute in series using async.series. All the functions run but they do not finish in series. I'm new to node.js and I'm struggling to figure this out. Here is my code I'm using.

```
async.series([
        function(callback){
        printRevision(peripheral, chars);
        callback();
        },
        function(callback){
                setInterface(chars);
        callback();
        },
        function(callback){
                performLoopTest(peripheral, chars, 0);
        callback();
        },
        function(callback){
        verifyResults();
        callback();
        }],
        function(err){
        console.log(err)
        }
    )

function printRevision(peripheral, chars) {
    if (DIS_FWREV_UUID in chars) {
        chars[DIS_FWREV_UUID].read(function(error, data) {
        // Ignore errors; missing FW revision is OK
            if (data) {
                console.log(
                    "Bootloader firmware revision: " +
                    data.toString('ascii'));
                }

        });
    } 
    else {
    }
}

function setInterface(chars) {
    var buf = new Buffer(4);
    var byteBuf = new Buffer(1);
    var retBuf = 0;
    var uint8Buf = 0;

    console.log("Setting interface to RS232")

    packet = chars[GIM_CONTROL_CHAR_UUID];
    byteBuf.writeUInt8(GIM_SET_INTERFACE_RS232, 0);
    packet.write(byteBuf, false, function(err) {
        checkError(err);
        console.log("set interface done")
    }); 
}

function performLoopTest(peripheral, chars, writeIndex) {
    var byteBuf = new Buffer(1);
    control = chars[GIM_TX_CHAR_UUID];
    packet = chars[GIM_RX_CHAR_UUID];  
    for (var i = 0; i < WRITE_BUFF_MAX_LEN; i++) {
        byteBuf.writeUInt8(writeBuf[i], 0);
        console.log("sending data");
        packet = chars[GIM_RX_CHAR_UUID];
        packet.write(byteBuf, false, function(err) {
            checkError(err);
        });
    }
}

function verifyResults() {
    console.log(writeBuf);
    console.log(readBuf);   
}

function saveLatestData(data) {
   console.log(data);
   readBuf.push(data);
}
```

Here is the output I get from the code above. It seems to just jump all over the place. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
Setting interface to RS232
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
sending data
[ 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55,                 56, 57 ]
[]
undefined
Bootloader firmware revision: 1.0.7-release
set interface done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your async series is calling functions that in turn call `packet.write()` which is itself asynchronous. So the function in your series array returns after kicking off the `write()`. But the `write()` is asynchronous so it finally finishes at an undetermined time in the future.

If you need them to run in order, don't invoke `callback()` (which basically says "OK, I'm done, run the next function in the series) in the calling functions. Instead, invoke `callback()` in the asynchronous functions callback.

For example, instead of this in your async series array:

```
function(callback){
    printRevision(peripheral, chars);
    callback();
}
```

...do something more like this:

```
function(callback) {
    printRevision(peripheral, chars, callback);
}
```

...then change `printRevision()`:

```
function printRevision(peripheral, chars, callback) {
    if (DIS_FWREV_UUID in chars) {
        chars[DIS_FWREV_UUID].read(function(error, data) {
        // Ignore errors; missing FW revision is OK
            if (data) {
                console.log(
                    "Bootloader firmware revision: " +
                    data.toString('ascii'));
                }
            return callback(); 
        });
    } 
    else {
        process.nextTick(callback)
    }
}
```

Note that I have not tested this code but this hopefully gives you the idea.

You will have to make similar changes in other functions in your async series array.